# Nesting function_score inside a bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to combine the result of a `function_score` with other clauses inside a bool query.

```
{
  'bool': {
    'must': [
      {
        'function_score': {
            'query': {
                'exists': {
                    'field': 'field_A',
                }
            },
            'script_score': {
                'script': {
                    'source': "doc['field_A'].value / (doc['field_A'].value + params.pivot)",
                    'params': {
                        'pivot': 1000,
                    }
                }
            },
        },
      },

      {
        'rank_feature': {
          'field': 'field_B',
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The score stays the same, whether I include the `function_score` clause or not.

If I replace `script_score` with a `field_value_factor`, it does get reflected in the final score.

Comment: I'm surprised your query even runs, because it is not well-formed, you need to wrap each must sub-clause inside curly braces.

Comment: @Val It was more like pseudo-code. Fixed the syntax now.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, and what makes you think that the function score seems to be ignored? Can you bring up any example?

Comment: @Val The score stays the same, even if I remove the function_score clause completely.